# Python - subprocess - escaping in bash file

Tags: python, bash, sed, subprocess, escaping

I try to run a bash script from Python using subprocess:

```
val = subprocess.Popen([f"{dir}/bash_script.sh sk -s {variable} -l En"],
                              cwd=working_dir, shell=True
    )
```

But I have problem (probably) with this line in the bash script:

```
DIRECTORIES[i]=`echo ${DIRECTORIES[i]} | sed "s/${DIRECTORIES[i]}/\u${DIRECTORIES[i]}/g"`
```

Further in the script it creates directory named "uDirName" instead of "DirName".
I suggest the problem is escaping the "\u", but how to do it, when I cannot modify the bash file? (I cannot copy/etc into Python file, I have to use the bash script as it is)

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh.

Comment: @PM2Ring That applies to the shell used to parse and execute the command string in the `subprocess.Popen()` call, not the one used to execute the script itself; if the script has a proper bash shebang, then the script should run under bash. As for the original problem: what is that line even supposed to do? I can't think of a reasonable purpose for it other than to add "u" to the beginning of the variable (in an overly complex and fragile way).

Comment: @Gordon Fair points, but I figured that the `sh` stuff may be a useful starting point for the OP's investigations. We don't know what that script's shebang looks like. And I'm a bit suspicious of any script that has a non-option arg before `-` options. ;)

Comment: The \u in the bash line should turn the next character upper. It works perfectly when I run the bash script from command line.But it doesn't work when I run it from Python. Therefore I think there has to be problem with escaling the \u

Comment: shebang of the bash script: #!/bin/bash